# cannot find .h file even after installing ADALiOS pod

Tags: objective-c, adal

I installed ADALiOS using pods, and I changed the library search path as per the documentation but I still get file not found when I try the following include

```
#import <ADALiOS/ADAuthenticationSettings.h>
```

my search path are as follows

```
$(SRCROOT)/Pods/ADALiOS/**
```

I can see the file under the Pods folder/ADALiOS as well but I just cannot link it for some reason

Why is not being picked up?

EDIT --

if I drag and drop the header onto the file it gives me this include path and that works?

```
#import </Users/mdouhan/Documents/dev/NWMobileTill/Pods/ADALiOS/ADALiOS/ADALiOS/ADAL.h>
```

I don't understand why its repeated so many times?

Comment: Do you use Pods in your project? Are you using workspace created by Pods? I'm asking because if you use Pods correctly then all imports works fine.

Comment: Yes I am using pods and yes using the workspace and other pods works fine just ADAL don't work for some reason